# how does the function return in c++ work

Tags: c++, function

I want to know how the compiler save this temporary int if I call the function f(3);

```
int f (int x) { return x; }
```

and how this will be excuted by the compiler :

```
int a=f(3);
```

is it just like doing int a=x; (I know x will be already destroyed ) or it really create a temporary variable called f(3), like this `int f(3)=x;`

```
int& a=f(3);
```

and why this wont work ?

Comment: Are you asking how an optimizing compiler will treat this particular code, or about the general mechanism?

Comment: You can't do `int& a=f(3)` because the function `f` returns an integer and you're assigning it to a reference to an integer (`int&`).

Comment: @prelic : assigning an integer to a reference to an integer is perfectly valid. What's not valid is assigning a temporary to a reference.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen im talking in general.

Comment: @J.N. what is a temporary int, is it just like other variables will be placed in the stack ?

Comment: It's a variable you can't take the address of because it will be destroyed after the statement returns (to simplify). If you want to store it somewhere permanently (i.e. copy it), you need to affect it some storage. A reference, as the name suggest, is merely a name, so you can't bind the return value of a function to a reference. (well you could with a const reference but that would likely trigger a crash, don't do it).

Comment: It may or may not be placed on the stack. I am not sure whether this is guaranteed. There may be an intermediate, look for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Function calls

The compiler will do one of the following things:

1. Push the argument on stack and call the function

   - For a more complex function than yours, this will typically happen.
2. Load the argument into a register and call the function

   - This *may* happen when optimizing, and there are enough registers to hold variables that need to be passed around.
3. Optimize the function away completely (inlining)

   - For a trivial function like the one in your case, a sane compiler will do this with the most basic optimization level, so that you get the same assembly as if you did `int a = 3`.

#### Reference variables in C++

A reference variable, one declared as `int &a` in your code is "a different name for an existing memory location". So declaring `int &a` does not allocate space for an `int` anywhere. It just declares `a` to refer to an already allocated memory location.

This location may be an existing variable `int b`, so that you say:

```
int b;
int &a = b;
```

Here, `a` will refer to the same contents that `b` refers to. "A new name for an existing object" is a good idiom to go with.

You could get fancy and say `int &a = array[5]`, so that `a` refers to 6th element of an `int` array `array`, or `int &a = *(int*)0x12345678` to refer to a specific memory location, but I'm digressing.

Your code

```
int &a = 3;
```

cannot work, because `3` is a temporary object, which will be forgotten after the statement is executed. To understand the problem more fundamentally think of this: *If `a` refers to an already allocated memory location, what will it refer to, after the statement `int &a = 3` is executed, and there is no longer a temporary object `3`?*

This is also a common problem with reference variables in functions: returning a reference to a function-local object is undefined behavior... but I'm digressing again. You always have to have a "living, allocated object" for `a` to refer to, end of story.

#### A bit more in-depth on reference variables

What typically happens for a statement like

```
int a = 3;
```

is that the compiler generates code to (simplified):

1. load the constant 3 to a register
2. load the register to the memory location allocated for a

The point is: in either case, there is no long-lived memory location allocated for the object `3`, so an `int &a` really cannot be made to refer to this object because of that.

"long-lived memory location" means a location that will live past the assignment operation. The register where 3 is stored will be overwritten and reused probably *immediately* after the assignment operation, so it doesn't qualify even theoretically for the target of `int &a` (in practice, `int &a` can only be made to refer to a *memory* location, not a register, anyway).

Comment: if I have this function > int& f(int& x){return x;} and > int a=1; > f(a) ; 
so now f(a) is it just like any other variable ?

Comment: and can you give me any sources where I can understand how funtion returns work ? thanks a lot

Comment: How code generally works on this level is very, very complicated. Judging by your C++ understanding, I suggest looking up some books on compiler construction and computer architecture, or doing some university courses on those subjects. Having said that, I found a quick reference of register usage, depending on compiler and operating system [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions), but architectures other than x86 will have different registers.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on the calling convention. With `cdecl` (which is common), the function will return `x` in the EAX register.  It will then be copied into the register assigned to `a`.

Of course, an optimizing compiler will optimize the whole thing to:

```
int x = 3;
```

2. You can't have a reference to something whose object lifetime has ended.  The object lifetime of `x` ends when the function does.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable compiler could (and would) turn

```
int a=f(3);
```

into

```
int a=3;
```

The call would initially compile into something like pushing the return address onto the stack, then the argument; the function itself would compile to popping the argument, popping the return address and pushing the argument again, then branching to the return address. A trivial optimizer would detect that no useful work was done, and optimize the whole thing away.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you call a function f(3) the instruction address of the calling statement gets saved in a register and your instruction pointer jumps to the address of the first statement of function f. Also a new stack frame for function f is pushed onto the stack. When the function call returns a temporary will be created for the returned int from f(3) and this is what will be assigned to x when you do `int x=f(3);` (so returned value from f is created in a temporary which is then copied into x) so yes a temporary is being created for the return. The stack created for f(3) is destroyed as well.
2. `int& a=f(3);` doesn't work as a is a reference. A Reference is an alias. An alias is for something that already exists. f(3) returns a temporary copy to be assigned to a variable. As the stack is going to disappear after the f(3) call you can't really assign a reference onto that.

Answer (score 0):

`int& a=f(3);` - what isn't fine about this is that you're creating a reference to a *temporary variable*. On function exit, the data the reference refers to has been cleared and so it's now a hanging reference.

It is likely the compiler will just treat `int a = f(3);` as `int a = 3;` in the situation you outlined, but you can never be certain since ultimately this depends on the specific compiler and how it performs its optimisations.